# GSON, doesn't parse info for objects inside a list of another list of objects

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

I'm having trouble serializing a JSON, I hope you can understand my problem as I have some problems explaining it myself.

I'm trying to serialize a JSON object with GSON. Everything works fine, except when I have an Array of objects inside another Array of objects.

I have a class named Garden that contains an ArrayList of objects of the class Season which contains an ArrayList of objects of the class Schedule.

GSON parses the Garden and Season class fine, but when it comes to the Schedule class(the one inside the class Season) it detects that theres items to add to it, because it adds objects, the ArrayList of Schedules inside the Season class isn't empty, but the attributes of the class don't receive any contents, what am I doing wrong?

***My Garden class:***

```
public class Garden implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private float distance;
    @SerializedName("foto_principal")
    private String mainImageURL;
    ...
    @SerializedName("epocas")
    private ArrayList<Season> seasons;
```

***My Season class:***

```
public class Season implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("nome")
    private String name;
    ...
    @SerializedName("horarios")
    private ArrayList<Schedule> schedules;
```

***My Schedule class:***

```
public class Schedule implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("nome")
    private String name;
    ...
    @SerializedName("epoca") // todo delete after
    private int  epoca;
```

***Part of my JSON:***

```
{
meta: {
limit: 1000,
next: null,
offset: 0,
previous: null,
total_count: 11
},
objects: [  <- Here each object is a Garden
{
dificuldade: "Média",
duracao_visita: 60,
epocas: [  <- ArrayList of Seasons
{
    dia_fim: 31,
    dia_inicio: 1,
    horarios: [   <- ArrayList of Schedules
        {
            dias: [
                "0",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
            epoca: 1,
            hora_de_abertura: "09:00:00",
            hora_de_fecho: "09:00:00",
            nome: "aa"
        }
    ],
    id: 1,
    mes_fim: 12,
    mes_inicio: 1,
    nome: "Todo o Ano"
},
{
    dia_fim: 21,
    dia_inicio: 8,
    horarios: [
        {
            dias: [
                "5",
                "6"
            ],
            epoca: 2,
            hora_de_abertura: "09:00:00",
            hora_de_fecho: "09:00:00",
            nome: "b"
        }
    ],
    id: 2,
    mes_fim: 9,
    mes_inicio: 6,
    nome: "Verao"
}
],
especies: [ ],
latitude: 37.775318,
longitude: -25.314724,
```

}

***GSON Code:***

```
public static ArrayList<?> parseJSON(String json, Class obj) {
    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    if (json != null) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject root = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray elements = root.getAsJsonArray("objects");

        for (JsonElement e : elements) {
            JsonObject element = e.getAsJsonObject();
            dataList.add(gson.fromJson(element.toString(), obj));
        }
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem worked itself out, came back to work the next day and it was working fine. No idea what it could've been. I didn't change the code or altered any of the data coming from the JSON, oh well!

Edit: Uppon further investigation I concluded the problem was with the server sending information in an unsual way rather than the problem being with the application.